# Creating entity instance in doctrine migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I'm having this problem:

In a symfony2 application using Doctrine, during the first dev milestone, I created a migration to update the database schema. The migration I created was container-aware in order to be able to create standard entries in the entity manager (a Config entity instance) in the postUp method. This worked very well until today, when I created a new migration that adds fields in the config entity.

When I run doctrine:migrations:migrate here is what happens:

- The first migration runs it's up() method, tables are created according to milstone#1 mapping info
- The first migration's postUp() method is called, and it uses the entity manager to try creating a new config instance. But since at this point the second migration was not run, persisting the instance fails because database schema is not in sync with entity mapping info.

Is there any way to work-around this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine migrations: How to avoid SQL errors in the postUp step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529309/doctrine-migrations-how-to-avoid-sql-errors-in-the-postup-step)