# Symfony 2 + Doctrine Migrations cannot run through changeset due to entity changes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

We have an application that releases to production by tagged versions.

We want to always be able to go from the initial released version up to the latest commit via Doctrine Migrations. We also want to create dumps of the structure at the time of the tag being cut, and import that structure before running migrations.

If `1.0` has been cut and released to production, we want to start on our dev environments from that database snapshot and move up from there. The reason we do this is that unless we specifically go and checkout the git tag for that release, then run migrations, then go up to the next tag and do the same, we will always be working with the current code's entity structure.

Initially we thought this would work well - we will always match what production has and will be able to bring our database up from scratch to match production, apply untagged changed and know production will be able to safely be migrated up a version.

The issue with this is that if Symfony entities have changed between the initial release and the latest commit, attempting to go step-by-step through our migrations path will fail due to new (or changed/deleted) columns existing in current entities.

For example, say the initial release `user` table looks like:

```
| id | first_name | last_name |
|----|------------|-----------|
```

However, changes since then have added a `middle_name`:

```
| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name |
|----|------------|-------------|-----------|
```

Because Symfony will use the current Entity class code to work with the migration, and the `middle_name` column does not exist in the previous tags, this will fail.

Other than creating a script that runs `git checkout {tag_name}` commands, runs migrations and repeats for all identified tags, what options do we have to be able to go from version `x.x` to version `y.y`?

Comment: Doctrine migrations compare the doctrine schema and database, then produces a diff. What exactly is a problem for you?

Comment: @zerkms If we ran *only* migrations on a new application, this might work fine. However, part of our process is releasing a project with some sample data. Future migrations will affect this data either by editing their values (say we change a ROLE name from "ADMIN" to "SUPERADMIN" or changing the table structure. To get full confidence that our migration path will work we need to sed our database and then apply migration patches with data in place. However, having data breaks migrations because of mismatches between table columns.

Comment: And what is *the problem* there actually? Migrations work fine, and data must be managed manually in any case.

Comment: @zerkms managing data manually allows for introduction of human error. If we can start with `1.0`'s structure *and* initial data, then apply patches to the structure and data until we arrive at current, we can be 100% sure that migrations will succeed; going back and toying with old data can break this confidence.

Comment: You cannot resolve that: semantics of data exists only in our head (and in documents).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine migrations: How to avoid SQL errors in the postUp step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529309/doctrine-migrations-how-to-avoid-sql-errors-in-the-postup-step)